# How to generate GUI based applications performance /load on server /all reports?

Tags: jmeter

I used WebDriver sampler using selenium to create JavaScript for automating GUI-based applications. Here I traverse multiple pages. Now I want to know how much time takes to transfer the first page to the second page and also to calculate the total time from the first page to the last page .

In GUI based application which types of reports are useful? How to add this in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`WDS.sampleResult.subSampleStart` and `WDS.sampleResult.subSampleEnd`](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/#Reader-s-responsibility) to measure the timings for separate steps in a single WebDriver Sampler instance:

Example code:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.sampleResult.subSampleStart('Open example.com')
WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
WDS.sampleResult.subSampleEnd(true)
WDS.sampleResult.subSampleStart('Open jmeter.apache.org')
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter.apache.org')
WDS.sampleResult.subSampleEnd(true)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

and example output:

[image]

you will need to add the next line to [*user.properties* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) in order to enable the functionality:

```
webdriver.sampleresult_class=com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.SampleResultWithSubs
```

If you have multiple WebDriver Samplers and want to measure the cumulative time of their execution put then under a [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)